# how to get Select2 events on AngularJS

Tags: event-handling, angularjs, jquery-select2

im using angularjs with select2 for application dropdowns, but i cannot figure how to get the change event or some other, inside my Controller.

is there some way to declare the eventhandler function via attribute?,
like **ui-select2 data-on-somethinghappened="fnx"**?

or instead on my configuration? like:

```
appXpto.value('ui.config', {
    select2: {
        placeholder: 'Please select a value..',
        onsomethinghappened:function(e){ ... }
    }
});
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can bind controller functions to directive scope object and call them when a select2 event happens on the directive. Use `&` to bind the function. then call scope.myBoundFunction() to call that function with or without parameters.